# Probability of two sum and alternating sum of two random variables being of opposite signs

Tags: distributions, random-variable, binomial-distribution

Consider the random variables
$a_i,i=0,1,\ldots,n$ be random variables which take values from $\{-1,1\}$ independently and randomly with equal probability. Let
\begin{align}
S &= a_1+\cdots+a_n  , \\
A &= a_1-a_2+a_3+\cdots .
\end{align}
I want to  compute the probability that $S. A<0$.

Here is my attempt:

**Attempt**
Let $E_1$ be the event that $S>0$ and $E_2$ be the event that $A>0.$ To simplify things assume $n$ is even, to begin with.

We observe that $S>0$ if more than half of $a_i$'s are +1. Next, for the alternating sum $A$, we have $A<0$ when $S>0$, if more of the $a_i$'s that contribute to $S$ have an odd index than an even index. Precisely, we want $ 2P(E_1 \cap E_2)$. We have:

\begin{equation}
P(E_1 \cap E_2)=P(E_1 | E_2)P(E_2)=P(E_2 | E_1)P(E_1)
\end{equation}

Now,
\begin{align}
P(E_1) &= P(S>0) \\
& =\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align}

So,

\begin{equation}
P(E_2 | E_1) = P(A<0 | S>0).
\end{equation}

If $k \geq \frac{n}{2}+1$ are $+1$'s, then for $A$ to be negative, at least
$\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1$ have to have odd indices. That means,

$$
P(E_1 \cap E_2)=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \sum_{\ell=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1}^k \binom{k}{\ell}}{2^k}
$$

Therefore, we have:
\begin{equation}
P(E_1 \cap E_2) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \sum_{\ell=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1}^k \binom{k}{\ell}  \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k}  \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{equation}

Since we have $S A$, even when $S<0$ and $A>0$, by symmetry, we conclude that the probability $S A<0$ is twice the probability given above. Hence the probability

\begin{equation}
P(E_1 \cap E_2) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \sum_{\ell=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1}^k \binom{k}{\ell}  \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \displaystyle \left(\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k}  \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right).
\end{equation}

However, I am not sure whether this approach or my solution is correct. Kindly  correct me and point out the mistakes, if any.

Comment: Please check after posting whether the equations rendered correctly. I fixed some. And also, I have added the [tag:self-study]; check its scopes.

Comment: This is a truly interesting puzzle - does it have some practical background?

Comment: Although your approach is good, your result is not correct, unfortunately. Your approach needs a lot of care when finding the number of "good" arrangements for the signs of $A$ and $S$ to be opposite. I've added some closer comments on the difficulties in my answer.

Comment: I agree the approach is a good one and the idea is nearly correct.  The details, though, are tricky: getting the right endpoints of the sums is crucial and it is helpful to do some analysis to reduce them from a double sum to something less computationally intensive -- ideally a closed form, but that appears elusive.

Comment: Thank you all for  taking time to post these wonderful answers and insights

Answer (score 2):

**Generalizing this problem simplifies it.**

#### Analysis and general solution

I will change the notation slightly for this generalization.  Let there be $m$ variables $X_i,$ $i=1,2,\ldots, m$ (to play the roles of $a_1, a_3, a_5, \ldots$) and independently let there be $n$ variables $Y_j,$ $j=1,2,\ldots, n$ (playing the roles of $a_2, a_4, \ldots$).  Let $S_X$ be the sum of the $X_i$ and let $S_Y$ be the sum of the $Y_j.$  Define

$$K = \frac{S_X-m}{2},\quad L = \frac{S_Y-n}{2}.$$

Thus, in the notation of the question,

$$S = S_X + S_Y = m + n - 2(K+L);\quad A = S_X - S_Y = m - n - 2(K-L).$$

Now, the event $SA\lt 0$ is equivalent to

$$(m-2K)^2 - (n-2L)^2 = S_X^2 - S_Y^2 = (S_X+S_Y)(S_X-S_Y) = SA \lt 0;$$

that is

> $$SA \lt 0 \iff|m-2K| \lt |n-2L|.$$

Writing $\mathrm dF$ for the joint measure of the distribution of $(K,L),$ this gives

$$\Pr(SA \lt 0) = \iint_{|m-2K| \lt |n-2L|}\mathrm dF(k,l) = \int_{\mathbb R}\left\{\int^{-h(l)} \mathrm dF(k\mid l) + \int_{h(l)} \mathrm dF(k\mid l)\right\}\mathrm dF_L(l)$$

where $$h(l) = \min\left(\frac{m+n}{2} - l, \frac{n-m}{2} + l\right)$$ and, as usual, $\mathrm dF(k\mid l)$ denotes the conditional measure and $\mathrm dF_L$ the marginal measure.

---

#### Specialization to the question

In the question the $X_i$ are independent of the $Y_j,$ whence $K$ and $L$ are independent, so there's no issue with computing joint and conditional and marginal densities.  Moreover, because all the $X_i$ and $Y_j$ can only have the values $\pm 1,$ the distributions of $K$ and $L$ are discrete: **$K$ counts the number of $-1$s among the $X_i$ while $L$ counts the number of $-1$s among the $Y_j.$**  The double integral reduces to a double sum, suitable for computation with small $m$ and $n,$ while the repeated integral reduces to a single sum, practicable for large problems.

Writing $l^* = \min(l, n-l),$ $F_K$ for the CDF of $K,$ and $f_L$ is the probability function of $L,$ this can be expressed as

> $$\Pr(SA \lt 0) = \sum_{l=0}^n f_L(l) \left\{F_K(\lfloor\frac{m-n+1}{2}+ l^*\rfloor-1) + 1 - F_K(\lfloor\frac{n+m}{2} - l^*\rfloor)\right\}.$$

Finally, because the $X_i$ are independent and so are the $Y_j$ in the question, **$K$ has a Binomial$(m,1/2)$ distribution and $L$ has a Binomial$(n,1/2)$ distribution.**  Thus, $f_L(l) = 2^{-n}\binom{n}{l}$ and $F_K$ is given by a regularized Beta function.  Their symmetries permit the formula to be evaluated over only half the sum (and doubled).  There is, in general, no further savings: as far as I can tell, there is no closed form expression for this sum, even when -- as in the question -- either $m=n$ or $m=n+1.$  Thus, I haven't attempted to go any further.

#### Comments

It is instructive to plot $\Pr(SA\lt 0)$ as a function of the variable $n$ in the question.

```R
N <- 2:100
p <- sapply(N, \(N) f(N - N %/% 2, N %/% 2))
cols <- hsv(seq(0.02, .6, length.out = 4), .9, .8)
plot(N, p, col = cols, xlab = expression(italic(N)),
     main = expression(Pr(italic(SA) < 0)))
```

[image: plot of probabilities for n = 2, 3, ..., 100]

With a little patience (ten seconds or so), we can explore the asymptotic behavior with a line plot out to, say, $n=10\,000:$

[image]

*Of course* the result converges to $1/2,$ so interest lies in how quickly.

As you would expect, the convergence is $O(n^{-1/2})$ -- but **it depends on the residue of $n$ modulo $4.$**  When the remainder is $3,$ the value is always exactly $1/2,$ as a symmetry argument will show.  Otherwise, the convergence is quadratic, albeit with slightly different coefficients.

[image]

All plot the absolute differences between the values and their common limit of $1/2.$  The first three plots are on log-log axes (which works because all the differences are nonzero).  The near-linear graphs document the $O(n^{-1/2})$ behavior (although the slight curvature apparent in the first one, for multiples of $4,$ is intriguing).  The last plot, for $n\equiv3 \mod 4,$ uses a linear vertical scale because many of the differences are zero.  Clearly all those probabilities are trying to equal $1/2$ but fail only because of floating point imprecision.

---

Here, to be explicit, is an `R` implementation of the general solution.  It requires both $m$ and $n$ to be positive.

```R
f <- function(m, n, F.K = \(k) pbinom(k, m, 1/2), p.L = \(l) dbinom(l, n, 1/2)) {
  l <- seq(0, n)
  lstar <- pmin(l, n - l)
  F. <- F.K(floor(lstar + (m-n+1)/2) - 1)
  S. <- 1 - F.K((n+m)/2 - lstar)
  sum(p.L(l) * (F. + S.)) 
}
```

To serve as a check, here is a brute-force implementation of the double integral.

```R
f2 <- function(m, n, p.K = \(k) dbinom(k, m, 1/2), p.L = \(l) dbinom(l, n, 1/2)) {
  joint <- outer(dbinom(0:m, m, 1/2), dbinom(l, n, 1/2))
  nn <- outer(0:m, 0:n, \(k,l) abs(m - 2*k) < abs(n - 2*l))
  joint[!nn] <- 0
  sum(joint[nn])
}
```

And, as another check, these probabilities can be estimated through simulation.  This solution is specific to the Binomial probabilities in the question.  The first argument is the length of the simulation.

```R
fsim <- function(N, m, n) {
  X <- matrix(sample(c(-1,1), m * N, replace = TRUE), m)
  Y <- matrix(sample(c(-1,1), n * N, replace = TRUE), n)
  S.X <- colSums(X)
  S.Y <- colSums(Y)
  S <- S.X + S.Y
  A <- S.X - S.Y
  mean(S * A < 0)
}
```

Because the correctness of the formula rests on niggling details related to the parities of $m$ and $n$ and which is larger, here is a quick (one-second) study using simulated datasets of size `N = 1e5` (intended to yield close to three decimal digits of precision) covering a range of values of $m$ and $n$.

```R
N <- 1e5; i <- 1:4; j <- 1:4
set.seed(17)
matrix(sapply(i, \(m) sapply(j, \(n)  {
  round(c(`Double sum` = f2(m, n), `Sum` = f(n,m), `Simulation` = fsim(N, m, n)), 3)
})), 3, dimnames = list(Statistic = c("Double sum", "Sum", "Simulation"),
                        `m,n` = t(outer(i, j, paste, sep = ","))))
```

> ```
>             m,n
> Statistic    1,1   1,2  1,3   1,4   2,1  2,2   2,3   2,4 3,1   3,2   3,3   3,4   4,1   4,2   4,3   4,4
>   Double sum   0 0.500 0.25 0.625 0.500 0.25 0.625 0.375   0 0.375 0.188 0.500 0.375 0.188 0.500 0.297
>   Sum          0 0.500 0.25 0.625 0.500 0.25 0.625 0.375   0 0.375 0.188 0.500 0.375 0.188 0.500 0.297
>   Simulation   0 0.501 0.25 0.624 0.498 0.25 0.622 0.373   0 0.374 0.188 0.501 0.374 0.185 0.498 0.300
> ```

**You can see all three solutions agree.**

The single sum, though, is the most practicable:

```
system.time(f2(1000, 10001))
```

> ```
>   user  system elapsed 
>   2.47    0.27    2.92
> ```

```
system.time(f(1000, 10001))
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed 
>       0       0       0
> ```

Comment: thank you a lot for explaining it so nicely and taking it to next level

Answer (score 1):

### tl; dr: Correct result?

Although the original post contains many correct ideas, it ends up with a formula for $P(S>0, A>0)$ that can yield probabilities larger than 1,

> \begin{equation}
> P(E_1 \cap E_2) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \sum_{\ell=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1}^k \binom{k}{\ell}  \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \displaystyle \left(\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k}  \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right).
> \end{equation}

So it cannot be correct, unfortunately.

Sections below:

1. Correct result, and checking by simulation (R)
2. A few comments on the derivation of $P(SA<0)$ in the original post
3. Derivation of the correct result (alternative solution)

---

### 1. Partial correct result, and checking results by simulation

For $n=1$, obviously it is not possible that $S$ and $A$ have opposite sign. Here, $P(SA <0)=0$.

For $n>1$, $\color{red}{n \not\equiv1\mod 4}$, it is
$$
  P(SA < 0) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} P(SA=0).
$$

The probability that $SA=0$ depends on $n$:

- for **odd $n$**, $S$ and $A$ have to be odd. Therefore, $$P(SA=0)=0.$$
- for **even $n$**, we need to distinguish between even and odd $n/2$:

  - if **$n/2$ is odd**,
    $$ P(SA=0)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n/2}{k}^2. $$
  - if **$n/2$ is even**,
    $$ P(SA=0)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n/2}{k}^2 - \frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n/2}{n/4}^2. $$

Here is a simple R code stump to simulate the variables $A$ and $S$, here for n=6, and a function `pzero` that implements the formula for $P(SA=0)$.

```
n <- 6
nsim <- 100000
A <- S <- numeric(nsim)
index1 <- seq(1, n, 2)

for (i in 1:nsim){
  a <- sample(c(-1,1), n, replace = TRUE)
  Y1 <- sum(a[index1])
  Y2 <- sum(a[-index1])
  S[i] <- Y1+Y2
  A[i] <- Y1-Y2
}

# estimated probability that AS<0
mean(A*S < 0)

# estimated probability that AS=0
mean(A*S == 0)

# theoretical result
pzero <- function(n){
  if (n%%2 == 1) pz = 0
  else {  
    pz <- sum(dbinom(0:(n/2), n/2, 0.5)^2)*2
    if (n%%4 ==0)  pz <- pz - dbinom(n/4, n/2, 0.5)^2
  }
  pz
}
# check with theory
pzero(6)
```

---

### 2. Some comments on the attempt in original post

[The original post denotes by $k$ the number of $+1$s, and later, $\ell$ is used as summation index for the number of $+1$'s placed on even indices.]

- The formula for $P(E_1)$ is correct.
- It is not completely correct that,

> If $k>\frac{n}{2}+1$ of the $a_i$ are $+1$s, then then for A to be negative, at least $\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1$ have to have odd indices

but this is probably just a typo, and you meant *even* indices that change the sign.

- If $k=n$ of the $a_i$ are $+1$s, it is not possible for $A$ to be negative. So the "good" values for $k$ lie between $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$ and $n-1$, not $n$.
- to find the number of good placements for the $+1$s that give negative $A$, you say that $\ell$ have to be on even places. Then, you would have to multiply the possibilities to choose the odd places with the number of possibilities to distribute the remaining $+1$s on the even places. If we call $n_{\text{odd}}=\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$ the number of odd places, and $n_{\text{even}}=n- n_{\text{odd}}$ the number of even places, you get as possible good solutions $\binom{n_\text{even}}{\ell}\binom{n_\text{odd}}{k-\ell}$.

---

### 3. Alternative solution ($n>1$)

Instead of looking at the probabilities for $S>0$ and $A>0$, divide these sums up into the parts with odd and even indices,
$$Y_1:=a_1+a_3+\ldots \quad\text{and}\quad Y_2:=a_2+a_4+\ldots .$$
Then $S=Y_1+Y_2$ and $A=Y_1-Y_2$, thus $$SA= Y_1^2-Y_2^2,$$
and
$$
SA < 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad |Y_1| < |Y_2|.
$$

The $a_i$ being independent implies that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent.

Since $\frac{1}{2} (a_i +1)$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$ with equal probability, we can write
$$Y_j = 2 X_j - n_j,\quad X_j\sim\text{Binom}(n_j,1/2),\quad j=1,2,$$
where $n_j$ is the number of summands in $Y_j$.

##### Case 1) $n$ is even

Here, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are i.i.d. with $n_1=n_2=n/2$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&P (SA>0) = 1- P(SA <0) -P(SA=0) \\ \implies\quad&
P(SA<0)=P(SA>0)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}P(SA=0)
\end{aligned}
$$

The probability $P(SA=0)$ can be obtained from the binomial probabilities for $X_1$ and $X_2$, since
$$
  SA=0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad |Y_1|=|Y_2|\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 
  X_1=X_2\ \text{or}\ X_1+X_2=n/2.
$$

To calculate $P(SA=0)$ through binomial probabilities, we use that $P(X_1=k)=P(X_1=n/2-k)$

- If $n/2$ is odd, the events "$X_1=X_2$" and "$X_1+X_2=n/2$" are disjoint. Then
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
    P(SA=0)&=P(X_1=X_2) + P(X_1=n/2-X_2) \\&\quad - P(X_1=X_2\ \wedge\  X_1+X_2=n/2) 
  \\&= 2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\left(\binom{n/2}{k}\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\right)^2 - 0
  \\&= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n/2}{k}^2.
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- If $n/2$ is even, conditions "$X_1=X_2$" and "$X_1+X_2=n/2$" are both satisfied for $X_1=X_2=n/4$. Therefore,
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
    P(SA=0)&=P(X_1=X_2) + P(X_1=n/2-X_2) \\&\quad - P(X_1=X_2=n/4) 
  \\&=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n/2}{k}^2 - \left(\binom{n/2}{n/4}\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\right)^2.
  \end{aligned}
  $$

##### Case 2) $n$ is odd, and $(n+1)/2$ is even

Here $Y_1$ is odd and $Y_2$ is even. It is therefore not possible that $|{Y_1}| = |{Y_2}|$.

Now write $Y_1^*=Y_1-a_n$. Then again, $Y_1^*$ and $Y_2$ are i.i.d., and they only take even values. Since $|a_n| = 1$, we have the
$$
|Y_1^*|>|Y_2|\implies |Y_1|>|Y_2|\quad \text{and}\quad
|Y_1^*|<|Y_2|\implies |Y_1|<|Y_2|
$$
while
$$
(|Y_1|^*=|Y_2|) \ \wedge\ (\text{sign}(a_n)= \text{sign}(Y_1)) \implies |Y_1|>|Y_2|
$$ and
$$
(|Y_1|^*=|Y_2|) \ \wedge\ (\text{sign}(a_n)= -\text{sign}(Y_1)) \implies |Y_1|<|Y_2|.
$$
Thus, using symmetry,
$$
\begin{aligned}
  P(|Y_1|>|Y_2|)&=P(|Y_1^*|>|Y_2|) + P(\text{sign}(a_n)= \text{sign}(Y_1))\cdot P(|Y_1^*|=|Y_2|)\\
&=P(|Y_1^*|<|Y_2|) + P(\text{sign}(a_n)= -\text{sign}(Y_1))\cdot P(|Y_1^*|=|Y_2|)
\\&=P(|Y_1|<|Y_2|)=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

So $P(SA <0) = P(SA>0) = 1/2$ for odd $n$.

Comment: ,thank you for your wonderful explanation and detailed solution

Comment: Close, but not quite right.  This is a tricky problem, so it helps to perform checks by means of different solutions.  See the three methods I posted.

Comment: @whuber, you are right, great you came back to that one. It was too much of a shortcut in Case 2, and that one only works in half of the cases. I had cut down my solution too drastically at one point - I'll fix it :-)

Comment: @whuber, agree that one should check with different solutions, why I also posted a rudimentary simulation (not wrapped in a formula, and with for loops, to keep it most transparent, but the drawback was that I apparently forgot to change n to 5 and got excited about simplifying the solution for odd n...)

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the few valuable rectifying comments ,here is  a my attempt to answer the question using the approach suggested in the original (incorrect ) solution.It would have been too long for a comment .However the answer is not some elegant expression.\begin{align}
S &= a_1+\cdots+a_n  , \\
A &= a_1-a_2+a_3+\cdots .
\end{align}
I want to  compute the probability that $S. A<0$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $E_1$ be the event that $S>0$ and $E_2$ be the event that $A>0.$ To simplify things assume $n$ is even, to begin with.

We observe that $S>0$ if more than half of $a_i$'s are +1. . We have:

\begin{equation}
P(E_1 \cap E_2)=P(E_1 | E_2)P(E_2)=P(E_2 | E_1)P(E_1)
\end{equation}

Now,
\begin{align}
P(E_1) &= P(S>0) \\
& =\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align}.
Now to compute  $P(E_2 | E_1)$ we make the following simple  observations:

**Every +1 at an even place will contribute  negatively    and every -1 will contribute to positively in the alternating sum $A$** 
So given $S>0,$ we would wish to enumerate the ways in which the alternating sum $A$ can be negative .Let the number of +1's and the number of -1's that go to even places be respectively $l$ and $m.$ Since the  total number of even places is  $ \frac n2 ,$ we have the following constraints :
$$ 0 \leq l \leq \min\{ n/2,k\}$$ and
$$ 0 \leq m \leq  \min\{ n/2-l,n-k\}$$
With this arrangement and assuming $E_1$ ,the value the alternating sum will become:$$ (k-l)-l-(n-k-m)+m=2k-2l+2m-n$$ and this we need to be less than zero.
so the number of ways of arranging $k>n/2$ +1's and $n-k$ -1's  so that $A<0$ can be expressed as $$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=n/2+1}^{n-1} \binom{k}{l} \binom{n-k}{m} \binom{n-l-m}{k-l}  $$ subject to the constraints :
\begin{align}
 & 0 \leq l \leq \min\{ n/2,k\} \\  
& 0 \leq m \leq  \min\{ n/2-l,n-k\}\\
 &2k-2l+2m-n<0
\end{align}
This gives us $P(E_2|E_1),$ after taking probability of this  arrangement into account .That value  is to be multiplied by \begin{align}
P(E_1) &= P(S>0) \\
& =\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align}.to get the requisite probability.Again ,it is my humble request  to that mistakes ,if any be pointed out and kindly tell me whether solution through this approach is possible

Comment: Please compare your formulas to those I developed in my post in this thread and to the simulated results.  All of them contradict your solution, unfortunately.